# Count ?var in PHP url as true

Tags: php

I have seen some urls on facebook where at the end you see `&theater` I assume this means it's somehow setting `theater` to `true`. I was wondering how to accomplish the same thing.

For instance:

`example.com/page/?var`

In this url, `var` would be set true.

I know I can add `=true` to the end of it to make it have the desired value, but I am asking this for convenience.

Comment: see the docs here *http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
if(isset($_GET['var'])){
 // true if var is set, even if it is empty
}
```

It is seen as a syntax error when one starts to declare $_GET['var'] when it is not set. PHP will throw an error at you, when error reporting set. It is good to see if it is set in the first place. If the var is oly to flag "true", then that is accomplished by just setting it.
To accomplish setting a url with $_GET variables is just by adding them to a link the way you see them in the address bar.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: To me it sounds exactly what OP is asking about.

Comment: @GolezTrol - After adding some text to it. But yes, i would think that covers it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = isset($_GET['var']);
```

Now `$var` is a boolean variable.